# All adblock extensions disabled in Family Link managed chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, google-family-link

On my computer I have Chrome profiles for my children's accounts, logged into Chrome with their credentials.  These browsers are "managed by your parent", which is me.

Today I opened Chrome under my kid's profile to let them watch youtube on their account. Ads exploded everywhere.  When I went to extensions I noticed ublock was disabled; the toggle to enable it was itself disabled, clicking it did nothing.

I poked around in Family Link for any settings, but there was nothing specific to allowing specific extensions.

I tried many adblock extensions, none of them worked.

Are there any adblock extensions that can work on a Family Link managed browser?

Chrome version details from `chrome://version`:

- Google Chrome 117.0.5938.150 (Official Build) (64-bit) (cohort:
  Stable)
- Revision  e3344ddefa12e60436fa28c81cf207c1afb4d0a9-refs/branch-heads/5938@{#1539}
- OS    Windows 10 Version 22H2 (Build 19045.3570)
- JavaScript    V8    11.7.439.21
- User Agent    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
- Command Line  "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
  --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end --origin-trial-disabled-features=WebGPU --disable-nacl --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end --disable-nacl

Comment: Related: [All extensions disabled in Chrome managed with Family Link](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/172448/88163)